# How to check where view scope managed bean is lost/rebuilt?

Tags: jsf-2

I've problem with `ViewScope` bean. It loses it's state during some javascript operations (new view scoped managed bean is created). What I want to do now is to check in which phase view is lost. Is it possible to do it in phase listener by retrieving from `PhaseEvent`? If no, is there some other way to check when and why scope is lost/recreated? I'm sorry but I can't paste source code because it's commercial and relatively complicated. I'm also relatively new in JSF. We are using JSF 2.0.7 with jboss 6.0EAP.

Comment: As easy as logging the phase events and the bean's constructor itself!

Comment: You have mentioned you are invoking managed bean using javascript. This could be the reason and its not the way to use it. Use f:ajax instead.